# Question about requesting list of all elements from a Rest Api (conversion of json string to list of java objects)

Tags: json, spring, rest, httprequest

I am trying to send Get request with RestTemplate in order to get list of all objects from a very basic Rest Api. This page suggests two ways to achieve it (section 3.1 and 3.2)  ---> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list

I tried both of the options, the second option returns an empty list. And the first option ends up with the following error message:

> WARNUNG: Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Cannot deserialize instance of
>   `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
>
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]; nested
>   exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT
>   token
>
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

Then I tried to get the json string and to convert it to list of java objects. Here is the code:

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response  = this.getForEntity(uri, Object.class);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Object> response  = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Object.class);
String jsonString = response.getBody().toString();
Gson googleJson = new Gson();
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray arrayFromString = jsonParser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
List<Employee> result = googleJson.fromJson(arrayFromString, ArrayList.class);
```

And I am getting this error ----> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 112 path $._embedded.employees[0]._links.self.href

I appreciate your answers a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you using spring boot ?? if yes then, I have experienced the same problem when I was new and I resolved it by doing the following :

1. name in the JSON should be the same as the variable name in java.
2. if there is a list then list name in JSON should be same as java list variable name

ex:

```
CLASS
-------

    public class company
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<String> EmpList { get; set; }
    }

    JSON
    -----
    {
        "Id": "610",
        "Name": "15",
        "Description": "1.99",
        "EmpList": []
    }
```

Hope this will help to resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The names are same in JSon and in java. I tried many things, unfortunately I could not get it working.

Comment: could you please share your GITHUB link where your code is...i will be more than happy to look and try to solve your problem for you